# Use JavaFX in Kotlin multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, gradle, javafx, kotlin-multiplatform

The JavaFX gradle plugin works well for a JVM-only project, but I can't figure out how to add JavaFX as a dependency to a multiplatform project's source set. I tried to use the plugin globally, without success. I aslo tried declaring the dependency in this way

```
  val jvmMain by getting {
      dependencies {
          dependsOn(commonMain)
          implementation("org.openjfx:javafx:18.0.2")
      }
  }
```

but it does not work.

So how can I use JavaFX in a multiplatform source set ?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: The [multi platform plugin is an alpha version](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-dsl-reference.html). I would not advise using it. If you wish to use alpha software, I advise contacting the plugin developers and working with them to package your application.  This is the first question here about packaging a JavaFX application with that tool, so I don’t expect you will get a concrete answer here.

Comment: Alternate packaging options are listed in the [javafx tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info). The gluon tools may help you, depending on what your target platforms are, you could review their documentation or contact them if you would like more info on such solutions.

Comment: I am wondering on which multiplatforms you want to run JavaFX. It currently does not run outside of a JVM. For special targets like Android or iOS you would have to use GraalVM native-image with special tooling from Gluon. So just adding JavaFX to a Kotlin multiplatform project would not buy you much.

Comment: Multiplatform is plenty stable to use in production projects. I know very little about JavaFX, but most standard JVM libraries will work fine. However, as a comment above stated, JavaFX only works for the JVM target. For other platforms you'd need a different UI layer.

Comment: I want to use JavaFX only for the JVM target. I already tested javafx in a cross-platform project, it works. The problem here is that I can't add JavaFX in a multiplatform platform librairy as a dependency for a specific [source set/target](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-add-dependencies.html#library-used-in-specific-source-sets). Also, it's a project for fun so it doesn't matter to me if kotlin multiplatform is not yet stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching the JavaFX gradle plugin, it turns out that I have to use different JARs depending on the platform, as JavaFX has native components.
So I wrote this code that works to compile the library, I will look at the packaging later.

```
kotlin {
    targets {
        jvm()
        // Other targets...
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                // Common dependencies
            }
        }

        // Other source sets

        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                // As JavaFX have platform-specific dependencies, we need to add them manually
                val fxSuffix = when (osdetector.classifier) {
                    "linux-x86_64" -> "linux"
                    "linux-aarch_64" -> "linux-aarch64"
                    "windows-x86_64" -> "win"
                    "osx-x86_64" -> "mac"
                    "osx-aarch_64" -> "mac-aarch64"
                    else -> throw IllegalStateException("Unknown OS: ${osdetector.classifier}")
                }
    
                // Replace "compileOnly" with "implementation" for a non-library project
                compileOnly("org.openjfx:javafx-base:18.0.2:${fxSuffix}")
                compileOnly("org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:18.0.2:${fxSuffix}")
                compileOnly("org.openjfx:javafx-controls:18.0.2:${fxSuffix}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code replaces the plugin entirely.

Comment: How is your code finally supposed to run if your dependencies are declared as "compileOnly"? And I still don't see where this is a multiplatform project if the only platform is the JVM.

Comment: I put as answer the code that declares the dependencies for the JVM, but obviously it is part of a larger build.gradle.kts file. I updated the answer for more clarity.